# regex checking inside of quotation marks

Tags: regex, awk

I am working on a regex that can apply arguments like this

```
!($1~/^[A-Z0-9]{1,25}$/)
```

but only apply this argument to objects that are surrounded by quotation marks. In other words, the code inside the variable that is checked may look both like `AAA0123` and `"AAA0123"`. I need it to only check the `AAA0123` part validity.

A full snippet of code

```
!($1~/^[A-Z0-9]{1,25}$/) {print "1st field invalid";}
```

Comment: Try `/^([A-Z0-9]{1,25}|"[A-Z0-9]{1,25}")$/`

Comment: @mumpitz no it doesn't. OP tagged `awk`

Comment: what do you really want to check? `"foo"` **AND** `foo` or  only `"foo"`?

Comment: so I want to be able to check whats inside the quotes but not the quotes themselves

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your solution seems to have worked thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a grouping construct (`(...)`) with an alternation operator `|` to introduce an alternative for your alphanumeric pattern, just the same pattern but inside double quotation marks:

```
/^([A-Z0-9]{1,25}|"[A-Z0-9]{1,25}")$/
  ^              ^^              ^^
```

If you do not use a group, like `^[A-Z0-9]{1,25}|"[A-Z0-9]{1,25}"$`, the `^` and `$` anchors will get applied to the alternatives *separately* allowing partial string matches.

Comment: yeah when applied to group it works perfectly. could this also work for an empty field so ("^") where it will accept the quotes but not anything else or would that require a literal

Comment: @jordanb111 I think you may just replace 1 with 0, `{1,25}` => `{0,25}`.